# How bottle return binary files

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, bottle

I want to make `bottle` python web service to serve binary files like pdf, picture and exe with authentication.

Is it possible to serve all this files using bottle? I have hard time finding a tutorial for that.

How about the `performance`? Does bottle python handle hundreds of thousands downloads simultaneously?

I am planning to use it with `nginx` `uwsgi`.

Comment: Is there something wrong with setting the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: @drewk I like the bottle simple concept. I will try to look at plone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definately possible to serve these files using bottle. You simply serve them as static files. As far as authentication goes, I do not believe bottle comes with authentication support ( as far as I know ). When it comes to performance though, this is an area when it really depends on how you deploy it. In a regular threaded environment, where each request gets it's own ***regular*** thread, I highly doubt your server will be able to comfortably serve hundreds of thousands of requests at the same time. However, it is noted in the documentation, that `greenlets` may be able to let you overcome this issue.

## Resources:

Bottle static file serving: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#routing-static-files

Bottle greenlets: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html#greenlets-to-the-rescue

Answer (score 1):

If you are not in a hurry i suggest you to try uWSGI 1.9 (it is still in development but the first stable release will be in 10 days) and use offload-threads = n (set it to the number of cpus). In that way when you send a file from your app it will be asynced (and non blocking) served by a different thread, suddenly freeing your worker. Offloading is available in 1.4 too but it is not automatic for apps as in 1.9